# How do you convert all of the DateTimes in a project to UTC?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

People in different timezones will be using a website I'm building and currently all DateTime properties are in EST using dm-timestamps. Is there a simple way to make it so anything that has been, or will be created has all DateTime properties formatted in UTC?

Comment: _"Is there a simple way"_ – well, you have to convert the existing EST values in your database to UTC and then store new values in UTC (probably by setting your project's / server's timezone). This doesn't sound too complicated. What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: It depends what data you have and how far back these times go. Remember that the time-zone definition changed in 2007 so adjusting those values will require careful attention.